# Unity Cutting a hole in mesh

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, csg

I've set myself a stupid task, that I didn't solve couple years back, again.
I've got few meshes with normals pointing inside. Caves. Like mostly circular rooms and tunnels that should connect them. Making tunnels to connect to a room is not a problem, just have their sides open and make a connector that will hide connecting edges if there are some sort of artifacts. But what to do with rooms. I need to cut holes in random positions in walls.

Comment: I'd appreciate if people that find this remotely helpful would interact with this question. I want it to be visible in google search, so that others wondering on how to do this would find this question. I've been struggling to do this few years ago and finally I know how to. Don't want it to be wasted.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to use [Parabox CSG](https://github.com/karl-/pb_CSG) for boolean operations. But there was a problem. If I just take a box flip normals and try combining it with a room I'll get a recessions in walls, but not holes.
And then I tried to remove one face of that flipped cube and positioned it inside that flipped dome mesh, so that they do not intersect.

[image: magic cutout]

And in result I had exactly what I was looking for. A clean mesh. Cubes material is not present in the result, nor any triangles.

I hope it will help those few that try to do similar things and fail to find any semi acceptable results. With this you can go full procedural and do anything you want.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! I tried various searches and found nothing but ways to manually modify meshes by adjusting vertices and points and thelike.

Comment: I've figured out a nice way to poke holes by removing triangles also. This one is a bit messy. But still better than nothing.